# Bind LiveCharts Pie Chart PieSeries Values to properties in the code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, livecharts

I have the following a class containing properties that get their data values from a database.

```
    public partial class Fruit
    {

        public double Apples { get; set; }
        public double Oranges { get; set; }
        public double Grapes { get; set; }
        public double Bananas { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to bind these properties to the PieSeries Values in a 
[LiveCharts PieChart.](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Pie%20Chart)

When I try `Values="{Binding Source= Apples}"` the control breaks.
Can anyone help?
My code is below.
C#

```
using LiveCharts;
using LiveCharts.Wpf;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Wpf.PieChart
{
    public partial class PieChartExample : UserControl
    {
        public Fruit Fruit => new Fruit();
        public Fruit fruitData = new Fruit();
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FruitPieChartModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                "FruitPieChartModel",
                                                typeof(FruitPieChartDataModel),
                                                typeof(PieChartExample),
                                                new PropertyMetadata(default(FruitPieChartDataModel)));

        public FruitPieChartDataModel FruitPieChartModel
        {
            get => (FruitPieChartDataModel)GetValue(PieChartExample.FruitPieChartModelProperty);
            set => SetValue(PieChartExample.FruitPieChartModelProperty, value);
        }

        public PieChartExample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PointLabel = chartPoint =>
                string.Format("{0} ({1:P})", chartPoint.Y, chartPoint.Participation);
            DataContext = this;
            CreatePieChartData(fruitData);
        }
        private void CreatePieChartData(Fruit fruitData)
        {
            this.FruitPieChartModel = new FruitPieChartDataModel(fruitData);
        }
        public Func<ChartPoint, string> PointLabel { get; set; }
        private void Chart_OnDataClick(object sender, ChartPoint chartpoint)
        {
            var chart = (LiveCharts.Wpf.PieChart)chartpoint.ChartView;

            //clear selected slice.
            foreach (PieSeries series in chart.Series)
                series.PushOut = 0;

            var selectedSeries = (PieSeries)chartpoint.SeriesView;
            selectedSeries.PushOut = 8;
        }
    }
    public class FruitPieChartDataModel
    {
        public FruitPieChartDataModel(Fruit entityFrameworkDataModel)
        {
            this.AppleDataSeries = new ChartValues<double>() { entityFrameworkDataModel.Apples };
            this.OrangeDataSeries = new ChartValues<double>() { entityFrameworkDataModel.Oranges };
            this.GrapeDataSeries = new ChartValues<double>() { entityFrameworkDataModel.Grapes };
            this.BananaDataSeries = new ChartValues<double>() { entityFrameworkDataModel.Bananas };
        }

        public ChartValues<double> AppleDataSeries { get; set; }
        public ChartValues<double> OrangeDataSeries { get; set; }
        public ChartValues<double> GrapeDataSeries { get; set; }
        public ChartValues<double> BananaDataSeries { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Fruit
    {
        public double Apples { get; set; } = 6;
        public double Oranges { get; set; } = 4;
        public double Grapes { get; set; } = 8;
        public double Bananas { get; set; } = 5;
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Wpf.PieChart.PieChartExample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf.PieChart"
    xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:PieChartExample}"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="500"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <lvc:PieChart
            DataClick="Chart_OnDataClick"
            DataTooltip="{x:Null}"
            Hoverable="False"
            LegendLocation="Bottom">
            <lvc:PieChart.Series>
                <lvc:PieSeries
                    Title="Apples"
                    DataLabels="True"
                    LabelPoint="{Binding PointLabel}"
                    Values="{Binding FruitPieChartModel.AppleDataSeries}" />
                <lvc:PieSeries
                    Title="Oranges"
                    DataLabels="True"
                    LabelPoint="{Binding PointLabel}"
                    Values="{Binding FruitPieChartModel.OrangeDataSeries}" />
                <lvc:PieSeries
                    Title="Grapes"
                    DataLabels="True"
                    LabelPoint="{Binding PointLabel}"
                    Values="{Binding FruitPieChartModel.GrapeDataSeries}" />
                <lvc:PieSeries
                    Title="Bananas"
                    DataLabels="True"
                    LabelPoint="{Binding PointLabel}"
                    Values="{Binding FruitPieChartModel.BananaDataSeries}" />
            </lvc:PieChart.Series>
        </lvc:PieChart>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This code incorporates the valuable suggestions made by BionicCode.

Unfortunately I cant get the software to run because I am encountering a "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Please advise what I am doing wrong?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property `Apples` doesn't exist and instance of `Fruit`exists. You have to add a property to your `UserControl` and create an instance of `Fruit`.
Additionally the type of the properties must be a collection of type `ChartValues<T>`.

Since `Fruit` is a POCO returned by the Entity Framework you have to create a wrapper class for charts to serve as the chart model.

**FruitPieChartDataModel.cs**

```
public class FruitPieChartDataModel
{
  public FruitPieChartDataModel(Fruit entityFrameworkDataModel)
  {
    this.AppleDataSeries = new ChartValues<double>() { entityFrameworkDataModel.Apples };
    this.OrangeDataSeries = new ChartValues<double>() { entityFrameworkDataModel.Oranges };
    this.GrapeDataSeries = new ChartValues<double>() { entityFrameworkDataModel.Grapes };
    this.BananaDataSeries = new ChartValues<double>() { entityFrameworkDataModel.Bananas };
  }

  public ChartValues<double> AppleDataSeries { get; set; }
  public ChartValues<double> OrangeDataSeries { get; set; }
  public ChartValues<double> GrapeDataSeries { get; set; }
  public ChartValues<double> BananaDataSeries { get; set; }
}
```

**PieChartExample.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class PieChartExample : UserControl
{   
  public static readonly DependencyProperty FruitPieChartModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "FruitPieChartModel",
    typeof(FruitPieChartDataModel),
    typeof(PieChartExample),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(FruitPieChartDataModel)));

  public FruitPieChartDataModel FruitPieChartModel
  {
    get => (FruitPieChartDataModel) GetValue(PieChartExample.FruitPieChartModelProperty);
    set => SetValue(PieChartExample.FruitPieChartModelProperty, value);
  }

  private void CreatePieChartData(Fruit fruitData)
  {
    this.FruitPieChartModel = new FruitPieChartDataModel(fruitData);
  }

  ...
}
```

Then you can bind the pie chart to the FruitPieChartModel property:

**PieChartExample.xaml**

```
<lvc:PieSeries Title="Apples" 
               Values="{Binding FruitPieChartModel.AppleDataSeries}" 
               DataLabels="True"
               LabelPoint="{Binding PointLabel}"/>
```

If you want to set a `Binding` on the `FruitPieChartModel` property (as a binding target) then you must make it a `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: Thanks BionicCode.That enables the binding just fine.
However, my Fruit Class is created by Entity Framework and populated with integer data values from the database.
So I need to convert the integer values of the fruit properties derived from the EF class into the ChartValues<double>  properties that I use to define the pie chart segments.
It seems that I will have to convert the double type of the properties in the EF derived class to the ChartValues<double> type of the PieSeries elements.

 Apples = (ChartValues<double>)Apples_EF; Fails.

Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: You need to create a wrapper class for the chart as data model. I updated the answer to address your problem.

Comment: Bionic you wouldn't believe how helpful you are.  
I have pasted all your recommendations into the code above.
If you can just please stay with me and advise how to solve the System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' exception.

Comment: Sure. Have you called `CreatePieChartData(Fruit fruitData)`? Where is the exception thrown? Please help.

Comment: Yes.  I've pasted the latest version of the code over the original. 
You'll see I call CreatePieChartData(Fruit fruitData) from inside the PieChartExample() constructor.
It seems to hit the exception when it tries to execute the XAML  Values="{Binding FruitPieChartModel.AppleDataSeries}"

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. This makes sense as the  `InitializeComponent`  is invoked before the property `FruitPieChartModel`  is initialized. Therefore the bindings won\t refresh afterwards as we  are binding to a common CLR property. I replaced this property with a `DependencyProperty`. You can copy it from the updated example. I wanted to keep it simple that's why didn't implement the property as a `DependencyProperty` in first the place. Better aways use  a `DependencyProperty`  inside a control when you need a property.

Comment: Sorry BionicCode, I can't see where you created the Dependency Property.
Would you mind pasting it into the example code for me?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Seems like I forgot to save the edit. But NOW it's there. I think everything should work now.

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks for your vital and essential input.